# invoke_result with member (operator[]) function

Tags: c++, operators, c++17, member-functions, invoke-result

How do I call invoke_result correctly for a member function? Or specifically for an operator member function. I tried `std::invoke_result<T::operator[], size_type>` to no success. What would be the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I simply thought my code would be misleading, since it would just detract from the main question. `T` here is a template typename anyways, so it should work in general for any class providing an `operator[]` with one argument of `size_t`.

Comment: I think you underestimate people willing to help. :-)   
Your code will extremely seldom be mislleading!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't doubt people's willingness to help, I just know I probably wouldn't do a good job of providing a non-misleading minimal example. I've been there, I have done that. It usually turns out bad, because I have irrelevant details in my code which mislead the people trying to answer, so I try my best to provide only the minimal necessary details as of late.

Comment: @ightxbulb - Ok, let's hope your future at SO will be nice. I get my wrist slapped every now and then - and I've got 40 years in the business. It's not an easy game - but it's worth every minute!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't. Use `decltype(std::declval<T&>()[size_type{}])` or something similar (adjust the value category and the cv-qualification as needed).

`invoke_result` is for when you have an invocable/callable object. You don't have one, so don't try to hammer square pegs into round holes.

Comment: This works. I assume it doesn't construct T by calling declval though, does it? Since T in this case is quite large.

Comment: @lightxbulb `decltype` takes an unevaluated operand. So no, it constructs nothing at runtime.

Comment: Does this imply that it constructs it at compile time though (possibly increasing compilation time if there are multiple compile time invocations of this)?

Answer (score 5):

What about as follows ?

```
std::invoke_result<decltype(&T::operator[]), T, size_type>
```

But this syntax should works with a single, and not template, `operator[]`.

In case of template or overload, you should avoid `std::invoke_result` and follows the `decltype()` way suggested by T.C.

Or, maybe, you can wrap the call in a lambda function and apply `std::invoke_result` to the lambda (if you really, really want to use `std::invoke_result`).

Regarding the `std::invoke_result` syntax, take in count that a pointer to a member function is a completely different things, compared to a pointer to a regular function. Anyway, you can roughly see it as a pointer to a regular function receiving an additional argument (in first position) corresponding to the object that call its method.

So, in your example, the first `T` argument represent the object of type `T` that call its operator.

Comment: I get a `cannot determine which instance of overloaded function ... is intended`.

Comment: @lightxbulb - I suppose you have more `operator[]` (`const` and not-`const` version?) in your class.

Comment: @lightxbulb: Perhaps you should update your question with a [mcve] then.

Comment: @max66 There's a const and non-const version of it, yes. No other overload. Is this what's causing the issue?

Comment: @lightxbulb - yes, I suppose is it. As said: "this syntax should works with a single, and not template, operator[]". To verify, try commenting the non-const version to see if the error disappear.

Comment: @max66 Yes, this seems to have been a problem, while I couldn't comment out any of the operators since this was breaking the whole code, I tested it by defining a new operator and it turned out it's specifically the const overload causing the issue. T.C.'s answer seems indeed a more adequate solution to what I am trying to do.

Comment: @lightxbulb - I'm agree. I've tried to explain the syntax for `std::invoke_result` and member functions but I think it's a bad idea to use it to detect the returned type of a specific method. The T.C. solution is, IMHO, a better solution because works also in case of overloading and template methods.

Comment: @lightxbulb - Anyway, isn't exactly "the const overload causing the issue". There is nothing wrong with the `const` version. The issue is caused by the presence of more than one `operator[]`, so the compiler doesn't know which one choose when you write `decltype(&T::operator[])`.

Comment: @max66 Is there a specific syntax to invoke specifically the const version in this case? I tried swapping `T` with `const T` to see if it will work, but this didn't produce results. How does one go about resolving such ambiguities? I would assume that one can differentiate between the different overloads through the argument types given, however what can I do for the `const` vs `non-const` case. (I am asking out of curiosity - I do not plan to use this rather than T.C.'s version, but I assume there are cases where `invoke_result` is a valid solution).

Comment: @lightxbulb - sorry but... if there is a specific syntax, I don't know it. But with T.C. solution, you can add `const` to the `std::declval()` type: `decltype(std::declval<T const &>()[size_type{}])`

Comment: @max66 T.C.'s solution works either way. I was just curious what the correct syntax for resolving the ambiguity would have been for the `invoke_result` version. It's not tragic though.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Tank you! Thanks to your hint, I got the following 
code:
struct C_STRUCT { 
    double Func(char, int&) { return 3.14; }; 
};
std::invoke_result<decltype(&C_STRUCT::Func), C_STRUCT, 
char, int&>::type   dbl_var_g = 3.14;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(dbl_var_g), 
double>::value, "Несоответствие типов");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35747036)