# C++ get return type of a pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, c++20

If I have a pointer to a member function, is there a way in C++20 to get the return type from it?  In the example below, I can get the type of a member variable and the type of a pointer to a member function, but, despite a lot of searching, I can't find how to get the return type of a member function from a pointer to that member function, even though it feels like it ought to be something that the compiler knows.

Please note that I am specifically asking about C++20.  This question [How can I determine the return type of a C++11 member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107041/how-can-i-determine-the-return-type-of-a-c11-member-function) does not help me as it proposes the use of `std::result_of`, which is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test(int value) : m_value{value} {return;}
    int getValue() {return m_value;}
    int m_value;

};

int main() {
    Test x{123};
    auto functionPointer = &Test::getValue;
    std::cout << typeid(x.m_value).name() << "\n";                 // Prints "i"
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(&Test::getValue)).name() << "\n"; // Prints "M4TestFivE"
    std::cout << typeid(functionPointer).name() << "\n";           // Prints "M4TestFivE"
    // std::cout << ???(functionPointer).name() << "\n";           // Want to print "i"
    return 0;
}
```

I looked at `std::declval`, `std::invoke_result` and similar, but they all seem to be for similar-but-different problems.

Comment: The return type of the pointed-to function is indeed part of a function pointer type, but I don't know any way to extract that programmatically.  What do you want to do with it?  Maybe there's another way to achieve that.

Comment: The returned type of the function pointer is the type of the call `(x.*functionPointer)()`. To display it: `typeid(decltype((x.*functionPointer)())).name()`. And `std::declval()` and `std::invoque_result` can also be used.

Comment: See the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107041/how-can-i-determine-the-return-type-of-a-c11-member-function#comment112925437_26107594) that mentions `invoke_result`

Comment: But that comment is incorrect.  You can't use `invoke_result` on a pointer to a member function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910387/invoke-result-with-member-operator-function for example.

Comment: `template<typename MFPTR> struct helper; template<typename R, typename O, typename... A> struct helper<R(O::*)(A...)> {  using type = R; }; template<auto MFPTR> using mfptr_return_t = typename helper<decltype(MFPTR)>::type;` Now you can say `mfptr_return_t<&Test::getValue>` and it will produce `int`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The real question is why the standard library doesn’t provide that (with all the _cv_- and ref-qualified versions, `noexcept`, and C varargs).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks - that seems to do the trick!  (It would be nice if there were a more "built-in" way to do this, but I guess we have to wait for a future version of C++.)